# $\forall n\ \neg\exists d\,\, d\mid n\wedge\sqrt{n}\leq d\leq\sqrt[3]{n^2}\implies\exists p\in\mathbb{P}\, p\mid n\wedge\sqrt[3]{n^2}\leq p$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, integers

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ $$\neg\exists_{d\in\mathbb{N}}{ d\mid n \wedge \sqrt{n} \leq d \leq \sqrt[3]{n^2}} \implies \exists_{p\in\mathbb{P}}{ p\mid n \wedge \sqrt[3]{n^2} \leq p}$$

where $\mathbb{P}$ is set of all primes.

Obviously it has something to do with the fact that dividers of $n$ are evenly distributed on both sides of $\sqrt{n}$ but i couldn't get any further. Could somebody help please?

Comment: Please do not give answers. This is a problem from an ongoing contest. https://om.mimuw.edu.pl/static/app_main/problems/om72_1.pdf